# What does it mean to have a POSIX-compliant operating system?

Tags: posix

What does it mean if the operating system is said to be POSIX-compliant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you want/need to know about [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), and [POSIX-compliant OSes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems) in particular.

POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface for Unix) is simply a set of standards that define how to develop programs for UNIX (and its variants). Being POSIX-compliant for an OS means that it supports those standards (e.g., [APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)), and thus can either natively run UNIX programs, or at least porting an application from UNIX to the target OS is easy/easier than if it did not support POSIX. Of course, the level of compliance is not necessarily 100% and can vary (e.g., not all features are supported or may be implemented differently).

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that the operating system complies with the POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface for Unix) family of IEEE standards. Five minutes on Google will give you a list of compliant OS' and that actual content of the standards.